# Query using $dateFromString and $lt and $lge in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to return some records for date range from mongodb and I am trying to use the following query to query the collection test for the field StartDate:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "StartDate": {
        "$gte": [
          {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "2021-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
            }
          }
        ],
        "$lt": [
          {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "2021-04-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The above query didn't return anything but I am sure there are some data between the dates. Any ideas what have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: what programming language you are using? just try in JS `{ StartDate: { $gte: new Date("2021-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"), $lt: new Date("2021-04-01T00:00:00.0000000Z") } }`

Comment: `$match` uses query operators, in order to use aggregation operators they need to be in a `$expr` expression

Comment: Hi, Turivishal, I was using JS before and it was working but the Azure Logic App doesn't recognize JS so I have to find another way to get this working that is why I am trying to use the pure Mongo query $dateFromString to first convert the string to date and compare but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Joe, I change $match to $expr and getting the error "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: $expr". I am running the query against Cosmos DB (mongo API). Maybe it is not supported in CosmosDB ?

Comment: ohh https://mongoplayground.net/p/IKGjeRmOOec

Comment: You are correct, Cosmos doesn't support $expr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$dateFromString` is a aggregation pipeline operator, so it requires to match in [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression condition, and expression have different syntax of [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/),

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              "$StartDate",
              {
                "$dateFromString": {
                  "dateString": "2021-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              "$StartDate",
              {
                "$dateFromString": {
                  "dateString": "2021-04-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJavF7yl5Gd)

---

Second option: You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) operator alternate of `$dateFromString`,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UIELlqKybEl)

---

Update as per new requirement:

Field `activities.dateOfActivity` is an array, it requires to iterate through loop and check each date's conditions,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `activities.dateOfActivity` array and put both condition inside, it will return true if both condition satisfy otherwise return false
- `$anyElementTrue` will check return array of boolean have any true condition then return document

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "$expr": {
            $anyElementTrue: {
              $map: {
                input: "$activities.dateOfActivity",
                in: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      "$gte": [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          "$dateFromString": {
                            "dateString": "2021-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$lt": [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          "$dateFromString": {
                            "dateString": "2021-04-20T00:00:00.0000000Z"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPLAamn6q5v)

Comment: "$StartDate" is the DateFieldinmyCollection ? For example, my date field is called SystemCreatedDate, should I just replace "$StartDate" to be "SystemCreatedDate"?

Comment: `StartDate` is a Date field in your collection and $ is requires to give reference to that field in expression.

Comment: you can use `$SystemCreatedDate` instead of `$StartDate` in condition.

Comment: So if the field is in an array I should change it to "$MyArray.MyDateField" right? I am getting "unknown operator: $expr" error when running on CosmosDB. Looks like $expr is not currently supported..

Comment: might be its not supported in cosmosdb i just seen this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34251223-support-mongodb-s-expr-operation), follow this if you get anything.

Comment: I tried the query locally , no error this time but not returning anything. I am sure there are some records should be returned...

Comment: just paste the sample document in playground and share the link i will check.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/p_0wURpEYOl I add the sample data and query. When I run locally, it returns nothing.

Comment: the field is inside array so that is different think i have updated the query.

Comment: Thanks Turivishal. Is there anyway to avoid $expr as CosmosDB doesn't support it yet ?

Comment: no i don't know about cosmosdb but in mongodb there is no way except $expr to execute this kind of operations. or you have to find how to create date type and pass date direct like new Date() without $expr.